# Could we fork Ethereum and make Ether ERC-20 compliant?

Tags: ether, erc-20, forks

Is it possible for some future fork to make Ethereum ERC-20 compliant?

Since ERC-20 didn't exist at the beginning of Ethereum, I'm curious if it would be beneficial for Ether to interact more directly with ERC-20 tokens, without the need for Wrapped Ethereum.

Comment: It should be possible, but IMHO it is not worth the effort.

Comment: Could you say more? 

I'm also curious about the difference between "not worth implementing it on the main active Ethereum chain" versus "not worth implementing even if you re-write Ethereum from scratch"

Comment: It is agreed that ERC20 has some issues, like required two transaction for approve+trasnferFrom, a wrong approve can be front run. A proposed implementation has to decide how to deal with old transaction that do not behave like ERC20. Also what to do about WETH, and similar contracts.